# Gstreamer sdk media player tutorial error

Tags: android, media-player, gstreamer

I am able to successfully build and compile all the gstreamer tutorials.In case of the 5th tutorial, I gave the default uri as `file://C:/users/abc/desktop/one.mp4`. After building and compiling the application successfully, the output screen displays no such resource found.

Addtionally, in the same tutorial, if I fetch the file from sd card, in the case of .mp4 file, the error written is `"Error received from armvideodec-omxgoogleh 264 decoder: Internal data stream error" and in case of .ts file the error is error received from element decodebin21 : Your Gstreamer installation is missing a plugin`.

The logcat displays `GStreamer+basesrc error. gst_base_src_activate_pull :Failed to start pull mode`.Please help

Comment: I am not able to stream any .mp4 video using rtp. What I am doing is streaming .mp4 file from VLC and receiving it on emulator. In the 5th tutorial of Gstreamer, I am providing the uri rtp//234.5.6.7:5544 but the emulator displays no uri handler defined for rtp. Does anyone have idea regarding this?

Comment: When I add the rtp in the uri field, emulator shows the message URI handler not implemented for rtp. So, what is the solution for that? Also, .mp4 files are playing but I am not able to see the video, only the audio is executed. What would be the reason for that?